# Why can't I declare and assign global variable in a header file, even when using #ifndef HEADER_H

Tags: c, gcc

I saw some similar questions, but in none of them, the `#ifndef HEADER_H` was mentioned.

I have a header file and 2 C files:
 `constants.h`
 `main.c`
 `mylib.c`

In **constants.h**:

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

const int NUM_OF_ITEMS = 22;

#endif
```

In **mylib.c**:

```
#include "constants.h"
... code ...
```

In **main.c**:

```
#include "constants.h"

int main() {
    ... code ...
}
```

When I compile using the command: `gcc main.c mylib.c -o main`, I get the following error:

```
/tmp/ccl55fv3.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `NUM_OF_ITEMS'
/tmp/ccyZhu6F.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

- I mentioned `#ifndef`, so why it happens??
- Is there anything to do except for splitting it to `constants.h` for declaration and `constants.c` for assignment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The include guard is required to prevent multiple-inclusion is a *single* translation unit during *compilation*. The error you have on the other hand is a *linker* error - because you have more than one translation unit (object file) containing the same definition.

In C one would commonly use `#define` to define constants as macros. This has downsides with respect to type safety.  Alternatively you can do one to two things:

1. Localise the constant in each translation unit by declaring it `static`:

   ```
   static const int NUM_OF_ITEMS = 22;
   ```
2. Declare it `extern`, then *define* in a single translation unit:

   ```
    extern const int NUM_OF_ITEMS ;
   ```

   constants.c:

   ```
   #include constants .h
   const int NUM_OF_ITEMS = 22;
   ```

Option 1 is common practice in C++ where the semantics of `const` are somewhat different than C, or at least more clearly defined, and unless a reference or pointer is taken to the constant, the constant will be inserted into the code as if to were a macro - i.e. there will be no distinct storage of the "variable".  In C code that may or may not happen, but it will work either way but potentially marginally less efficiently.

Comment: I don't see the problem with type safety: Every literal has a type in the same way a variable has. Regarding the last paragraph: Neither C nor C++ put any requirements on optimization. In both languages, occurrences of `NUM_OF_ITEMS` (if `const` and the declaration is visible) may or may not (but probably will) be replaced by `22`. Strictly speaking, a compiler could even replace every occurrence by a runtime-evaluation of `11 + 11`.

Comment: @mafso : 1) Try defining a literal of type char or short (or unsigned variants thereof) with a macro.  You could of course prefix with a cast I suppose.  2) In C++ it is *guaranteed* that a const variable will be replaced by a literal in this circumstance *unless* a reference is taken.

Answer (score 6):

Each translation unit (read .c source file) into which you include the header file results in a new definition of the global variable. That is why the linker objects to there being multiple definitions. Remember that `#include` performs text insertion of the included file. From the perspective of the compiler, each of your translation units contains distinct definitions of `NUM_OF_ITEMS`.

You need to define it in exactly one translation unit. You might consider adding a `constants.c` which contained the definition of `NUM_OF_ITEMS`, and leaving just a declaration in the header file.

Alternatively you could use a macro:

```
#define NUM_OF_ITEMS 22
```

Or as Jens suggests in the comment below, an enumeration constant.

Or as you yourself suggest, with `static` linkage so that the object is internal to each translation unit.

Comment: ... or an enumeration constant `enum { num_of_items = 22, }`

Comment: If I use C file, and I want the variable to be constant, will it work if I define a const variable in a header and assign it in a C file?

Comment: I also found out that if I declare it as `static`, it works. Is it a good practice?

Comment: `static` would be a sound choice

Comment: Do you like to add the `static` solution bolder in your answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: I could do that. Then again, why not accept one of the other answers? I think that they say it very well. I'd feel happier if you did that.

Answer (score 2):

In C (opposite to C++) constant objects have external linkake. So the both your compilation units will contain its own object with name `NUM_OF_ITEMS` and the linker will not know which one to use and allocate memory for it.

You could define the constant as having internal linkage that is when the object is visible only inside the compilation unit where it is used. To do that you have to use key word `static`

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

static const int NUM_OF_ITEMS = 22;

#endif
```